# how to set autogenerate id in room database

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

In the room database I want to auto generate id, I did the bellow code but I get `UNIQUE constraint failed` error.

How can i get the table to autogenerate id and I do not want to pass id

```
@Entity
data class OfflineDatax (
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val uid: Int = 0,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "requestJSON") val requestJSON: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "requestCode") val requestCode: String?
) 

@Dao
interface OfflineDataDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM offlinedata")
    fun getOfflineData(): Flow<List<OfflineData>>

    @Insert()
    suspend fun insertOfflineData(offlineData: OfflineData)
}
```

This is how inserting data

```
libOfflineDataDao.insertOfflineData(OfflineData(1,"test", "test"))
```

Thanks
R

Comment: Use `0` to auto generate ID for the inserted row.

Comment: Documentation supporting comment by @Nicolas: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/PrimaryKey#autoGenerate()

Comment: see these answers
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44109830/11586761
and
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50558275/unique-constraint-failed-room-database-android

Comment: @Nicolas when i changed it to 0 it did work, thanks guys

Answer (score -1):

we need the unique ID only to access the data but since you are just inserting the data and also you have set the default value as 0 to be inserted, Kotlin is smart enough to insert the data with just the rest two of the parameters. Please let me know if this has helped in any way.

```
libOfflineDataDao.insertOfflineData(OfflineData("test", "test"))
```

This should work too.

Comment: Hmm, no it won't.

Comment: Works when implemented a different constructor